# Adding index :unique to a column in ruby on rails via generate migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3.2, migration

I know that i can touch a migration and add

```
add_index :table_name, :column_name, :unique => true
```

But how is the right rails migration command to generate this?

```
rails g migration add_index_to_column_name :column_name, :unique => true
```

Is that right?

In my special example I have a table customers

```
  t.integer :customerID
  t.string :surname
  t.string :first_name
  t.string :phone
```

an i want to set the customerID to unique. Tried

```
rails g migration AddIndexToCustomers :customerID, :unique => true
```

But if i look to my migration file after this, it dont look right see this:

```
def change
    add_column :customers, :, :customerID,
    add_column :customers, :, :unique
    add_column :customers, :=, :string
  end
```

Any idea or suggestion?

Comment: Make sure not to use `> true` in your shell, or you'll create a `true` file via redirection.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Starting from Rails 3.2 you able to use:

```
 rails g migration add_index_to_table_name column_name:type:uniq
```

- as normal, type defaults to string

[Rails guide example](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/3_2_release_notes.html)

```
 rails g scaffold Post title:string:index author:uniq price:decimal{7,2}
```

#### Answer to the question

```
rails g migration add_index_to_customers customerID:integer:uniq
```

Comment: nope.. thats not working getting `def change
    add_column :customerids, :customerID, :string
    add_index :customerids, :customerID, :unique => true
  end
`

Comment: tried `rails g migration add_index_to_customers customerID:uniq` but still creates the customerID as a string.

Comment: I've added more examples. You can pass type into migration.

Comment: yeah this helps... doing new question for this strange adding the datatype

Comment: It should be add_index_to_table_name not add_index_to_column_name.