# How to add unique: true to already existing column

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, migration

I added a column to a table through a migration.It's generate a migration file i add the following thing. Then migrated.After adding that i realise to add forgot unique: true that migration. How to add `unique: true` to this migration file. Syntax please.

In migration

```
def change
  add_column :tasks, :position, :integer
end
```

Comment: check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16446814/adding-index-unique-to-a-column-in-ruby-on-rails-via-generate-migration

Comment: @Rajini, did you het it working?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add \`unique\` constraint to already existing index by migration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20467165/how-to-add-unique-constraint-to-already-existing-index-by-migration)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the old index and add it again with the new constraint:

```
def change
  remove_index :editabilities, [:user_id, :list_id]
  add_index :editabilities, [:user_id, :list_id], unique: true
end
```

(Credit: I directly lifted this answer from Baldrick's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20467218/1603071). Upvote him before you upvote me ;) )